# Finding the optimal combination of 2 processes

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

I am trying to figure out the optimal combination of $2$ processes $A$ and $B$. Process $A$ costs $ \$0.1$ unit, while Process $B$ costs  $\$1$ unit. Process $A$ gives a throughput of $2$, while Process $B$ gives a throughput of $10$. Both these processes are currently in function. Process $B$ is necessary whenever the throughput reduces on any given day. I am trying to figure out the right trade-off between (reducing) cost and (increasing) throughput that would help find the optimal combination of Process $A$ and Process $B$.

Can I use Linear Programming Optimization equations on cost constraints here?

Comment: Assuming you want to maximize the throughput, there is no trade-off to be performed with your processes. Process A has a better efficency and cost less (and the cost of B is a multiple of the cost of A). The point on the cost is that if you were to use the process B, you could use instead 10 times the process A. Maybe there are som information missing in your question.

Comment: Hi Marc, I have updated the question. I forgot to mention that the scale at which these processes must operate is in Millions. Hence, a combination of the 2 process is necessary on some days. I'm trying to find the right combination which would serve as a threshold limit.

Comment: I think you can read this : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3712503/minimizing-by-linear-programming . By the way, even with your new numbers, there is still no trade-off to be performed. Process A is still better is every aspect. Hum actually, in your description, since there are only two processes without practically any real constraint, the most efficient will always be the one to pick.

Comment: Could it be that you only can have one of each of these process or something like that ?