# Minimizing by Linear Programming

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, discrete-optimization

I have a linear program which I can't write its equations. The problem is 
An office furniture company has two plants that produce lumber used in the manufacturing of a line of desks and computer tables that the company sells. In one week, plant $A$ can produce the lumber required to manufacture 200 desks and 120 computer tables, while in one week, plant $B$ can produce the lumber to manufacture 350 desks and 240 computer tables.

Suppose it costs \$5,150 per week to operate plant $A$ and \$8,200 per week to operate plant $B$.

If the company  needs enough lumber to manufacture at least 2,000 desks and 1,320 computer tables, how many weeks should each plant operate in order to meet this requirements at the a minimum cost? What is the minimum cost?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to set up the problem:

**What is the objective?** - Minimise the cost

Total cost = Cost of operating plant A + Cost of operating plant B

Now, we need to introduce variables to quantify this. Let $w_A$ be the number of weeks to run plant A, and similarly $w_B$

Now, total cost $C$ is given as

$$C = 5150w_A + 8200w_B$$

**What are the constraints?**

You need to produce a certain amount of lumber to satisfy the demand. How can we use our variables above to express that? We need a total of atleast $2000$ desks and $1320$ computer tables

Hence, the number of desks we would produce is $200w_A + 350w_B \geq 2000$

Similarly, for the tables we have $120w_A + 240w_B \geq 1320$

Put it all together, you get

$$\min 5150w_A + 8200w_B
\\ \text{s.t} \\
200w_A + 350w_B \geq 2000 \\ 120w_A + 240w_B \geq 1320 \\w_A, w_B \geq 0$$

Comment: Thank you so much. It was very helpful.

Comment: Sorry I have problem again when I plot the lines they meet each other in (3,4) but when I consider two conditions they don't have common region for detecting feasible region. I a

Comment: The common region would be outwards wrt to origin, bounded by the axes